# I need to split a text field into 2 fields in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007, substring

I have inherited a really bad access database that I need to move the data out of it into a MySQL database.  I have a field that has some string data in it followed by an oddly formatted date in parentheses at the end.  I am trying to craft a query that has a field that contains only the string up to the open parenthese "(".  And a second field that contains only the contents of the parentheses.

Following advice I have found here and elsewhere I have tried

```
note: Left(notefield, InStr(notefield, "("))
```

but I get the error "Undefined function 'left' in expression." even though I built it using the Builder.  So any ideas what I should use in my access query to extract this data?  And it has to be in access.

Comment: Why does it have to be in access?  Why don't you extract the data as a single field, then fix it in MySQL, which is (IMO) much easier to work with.

Comment: because this is going back into a new access file.  Sigh.  And I cannot be doing the conversion, as we transfer over we have 2 months where we will be entering data in the old db, exporting it every Monday, putting it into the new database, then using the new database to run the tool. And Im not doing the exporting then importing.

Comment: My job kinda sucks some time...

Comment: How about putting an insert trigger in the MySQL database so that every time you upload a row to the database it splits the two fields, then just downloads those two fields (and note the original) back to your new DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB(A) is funny this way (I say it that way because this same problem shows up in VB6 as well as the VBA in Office applications)....

When built-in functions such as `Left`, '`right$`, `InStr`, &c. start throwing "Undefined Function" errors, it almost always means that you've got a problem with References. *Some* library that you have defined a reference to is missing or broken, and it's *not* necessarily the one that's reporting errors.

Check Tools | References... and make sure that nothing that's checked says it's "MISSING". If it is, either remove it or fix the link (you can Browse... to the .dll file if you know where it's stored).